# is there any way to display contents of .docx files as selected by a visitor on my django webapp?

Tags: python, django, docx, word-processor

i am creating a web application using django and i want to display the contents of docx files , edit those files and save it back to the local device.
Is django capable of doing this.

Comment: Yes you can. But, please, be more specific. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have not tried anything because i am not sure how to do it. i know i have to upload the file and then manipulate with the file.

Comment: i am done with the process of uploading the file.
How can i display its content on the web app